# html get for a user\pass secured website

Tags: ruby

I need to build with ruby the following steps:
1. enter the homepage of a website 
2. in  there is a specific html form I need to enter user\pass in it and click the input button (i.e. html post)
3. get the response (html + login cookie) from step 3.
4. do many html get request with the login cookie (otherwise I won't have permission for the page)

BTW I tried

```
url = URI.parse('http://www.example.com/todo.cgi')
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)
req.basic_auth 'jack', 'pass'
req.set_form_data({'from'=>'2005-01-01', 'to'=>'2005-03-31'}, ';')
res = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port).start {|http| http.request(req) }
case res
when Net::HTTPSuccess, Net::HTTPRedirection
  # OK
else
  res.error!
end
```

and it didn't work.

Thank you guys

Comment: Why does this have a "ruby-on-rails" tag?

Comment: While it is possible to do it using Net:HTTP, you should probably follow @Fortuity's suggestion in his answer and use [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/mechanize/). It's made for exactly this sort of thing.

Comment: @Ryan Bigg, Whoa! DUDE! Where'd it go!? :-)

Comment: @the Tin Man: I think it ran away IN FEAR.

Comment: WOOooooo, scary! It said "RAILS!" I love the shiver that goes up my back when I say that. "RAILS!" Oooo, it did it again. "RAILS!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several excellent Ruby gems for automated access of web sites.

See:

- the [Ruby Toolbox for HTML Parsing](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/html_parsing.html)
- the [Ruby Toolbox for HTTP clients](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients.html)

Nokogiri is the most popular gem for HTML parsing. Ryan Bates has an excellent [screencast on Mechanize](http://railscasts.com/episodes/191-mechanize). [Mechanize](https://github.com/tenderlove/mechanize) is a Ruby library for automated interaction with websites. It extends Nokogiri allowing you to interact with multiple pages on the site: click links, submit forms, etc.

Take a look at Mechanize. You'll get far with a well-documented Ruby library and save the work of implementing it yourself.

Comment: I'll second the suggestion to use Mechanize. It makes it easy to navigate pages, and deal with the usual session keys and cookies. And, because it's built using Nokogiri, you have a great parser underneath it to help locate form and page elements. Plus you can't beat the team working on it; They know their stuff.

Comment: @Oded Regev, if you think this is a good answer you can click the checkmark to the left (under the up/down votes) to select this is as the best answer.